# Publishing Docusaurus project on IIS

Tags: node.js, npm, iis, docusaurus

I have a Windows server. I created the "Docusaurus" project for Document, I run it on localhost:3000 port, I want to publish it on IIS, but I don't know how to do it, can you help me? ?

I have prepared the content of the project, I just need to publish it via IIS.

Comment: Just copy it over? Just like you would with any other static site.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's a node project

Comment: The official Docusaurus documentation suggests that you can deploy your site to a static site hosting service such as Vercel, GitHub Pages, Netlify, Render, and Surge. https://docusaurus.io/zh-CN/docs/deployment.
Since Docusaurus is a Node.js-based project, its default configuration may not work with IIS. There is no relevant documentation on deploying Docusaurus to IIS on the Internet. Perhaps you can refer to the related examples of deploying a Node.js application on IIS and gain some experience. Download and install the IISNode module, which allows running Node.js applications on IIS.